# Does AWS have an EC2 usage report available on the internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I'm doing some research to try and determine the most popular EC2 instance type used/consumed from commercial AWS services. I feel like the reason I can't find anything useful is because this is potentially sensitive information? I came across this [link](https://blog.vyos.io/vyos-usage-report-on-aws) but it does not encompass all AWS services or even a single region. The only thing I can infer/assume is that the free tier (t2.micro) will probably be the most popular (for obvious reasons). Beyond that is just a guess. Does AWS publish this information anywhere? Is there an annual report or an independent study that reports that information?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt AWS shares that information with anyone because it might be useful for google and microsoft (and any other competitor) to know to better compete against AWS.

Comment: AWS doesn't even publish how much money they make by different service, much less further break it down by instance types.  I also doubt you can infer almost anything from 400 users using one product.